# Next and Prev button not work when click both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, banner

i'm trying to use banner slider with jquery.currentBanner value increase and decrease when i click button but banner not change.

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentBanner = 0;
    $("#prev").bind("click", function () {
        currentBanner -= 1;
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $("#next").bind("click",function () {
        currentBanner += 1;
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).css("display", "block");
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="next>next</a>
<a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
<div id="banner_div">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you, don't forget to mark one of them as the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat

```
<a href="#" id="next>next</a>
```

is missing the closing quote for your id attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="next">next</a>
```

---

***[Here's a jsFiddle demo of what I would do](http://jsfiddle.net/eFUqj/1/).***

**jQuery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $images = $("#banner_div img"),
        totalImages = $images.length,
        currentIndex = 0;

    $images.eq(currentIndex).fadeIn("slow");

    $("#prev").on("click", function() {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            $images.eq(currentIndex).stop(true,true).hide(0);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            $images.eq(currentIndex).stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });

    $("#next").on("click",function () {
        if (currentIndex < totalImages-1) { 
            $images.eq(currentIndex).stop(true,true).hide(0);
            currentIndex += 1;
            $images.eq(currentIndex).stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });

});​
```

**CSS**:

```css
#banner_div img { display: none; }​
```

Comment: that was a problem but there's a bigger problem - the currently shown image never hides...

Comment: @ParthThakkar - I was simply providing an immediate answer to a syntax error I saw at first glance while at the same time I was creating a jsFiddle demo for any other underlying errors.  If you could revalue my post, I'd appreciate it. =D

Answer (score 1):

Compact version of Morteza's code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentBanner = 0;
    $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).show("fade");

    $("#prev").bind("click", function () {
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner--).hide("fade").prev().show("fade");
    });

    $("#next").bind("click",function () {
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner++).hide("fade").next().show("fade");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use methode $(selector).show("fade") and $(selector).hide("fade")

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentBanner = 0;
    $("#banner_div img").hide();
    $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).show("fade");

    $("#prev").bind("click", function () {
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).hide("fade");
        decrease(currentBanner);
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).show("fade");
    });

    $("#next").bind("click",function () {
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).hide("fade");
        increase(currentBanner);
        $("#banner_div img").eq(currentBanner).show("fade");
    });

});
```

when increase and decrease check  currentBanner beetween 0 and banners count.

```
function increase(n){
    n++;
    if(n >= $("#banner_div img").length)
        n=0;
}
function decrease(n){
    n;
    if(n < 0 )
        n=$("#banner_div img").length -1;
}
```